# Falha no JS do Mautic 2.14.1

Tags: php, javascript

Estou precisando de ajuda com o Mautic.

Qualquer página que acesso ele apresenta o erro abaixo:

"Mautic is not defined at dashboard:969"

Como se a class Mautic.js não existisse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa pergunta não pertence ao site porque não está em Português.~~ This question is off-topic because it's not written in Portuguese.

Comment: eu configurei o .conf do nginx do meu site e começou a funcionar.